# Black screen after wake after accidental greeter change

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I installed eOS a while ago and I'm pretty happy with it, but a few days ago came a problem. I was playing around with Solaar to get my mouse's SmartShift to work and I may have downloaded and ran the solaar-gnome3 package, which since then, I purged.

Since that change, my greeter screen changed from pantheon-greeter to a standard Gnome one and also every time i wake the machine, it stays on a black screen with no option for getting off from it other than hard rebooting the whole thing.

Is there anything I can do without reinstalling the OS? I have a lot of stuff already set up so that would be a darn waste.

My machine if it helps: Thinkpad T440s with i5-4300U with on-board graphics (Intel HD Graphics). Of course I installed additional drivers etc. and as I said it was working great for a long time.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it after a while. Probably some software update broke lightdm. All it took was purging and reinstalling it and after the installation choosing lightdm again. Works ok now.

Comment: (Please mark this answer solved, I'm glad it's fixed! I've had this happen in the past.)